# AngularJS $cookies are not persisting after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie using $cookies when a user is logged in.Here is what am trying .

```
AuthService.login($params).then(function (user) {
    $cookies.put('token', user.access_token,{'expires': expireDate});
    $rootScope.access_token = $cookies.get('token') ;
}
```

Everything works well except that the  that the cookie is getting set but its **not  persisting after page refresh**.

I have set the expiry date of 1 day too.

**Why is the cookie not getting stored like other websites do ?**

Am using firefox developer edition ,so no problem there, moreover am running the application on a local server.

Comment: Could you expose the value of `expireDate`?

Comment: @RahilWazir var expireDate = new Date();
 expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);

Comment: @dennyjohn please show - how you are read cookie content and more important - when. In the `run()` section?

Comment: $cookies.get('token-name'); @KrzysztofSafjanowski